# Why are there more questions when I'm logged in?

Tags: support

I've noticed in both ServerFault and SuperUser that when I click the "Questions" button, it shows a lower number of questions when I'm logged out.  Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We cache pretty aggressively for unregistered / anonymous users, so you're probably seeing older question counts in the "logged out" state. So there would be "more" questions when you're logged in because the display is closer to real time.

Comment: It's about 300 questions less for SF, that's about 4 days worth of questions.  So the question count I'm seeing when I'm logged out might have been cached from 6 days ago?  That is aggressive.